# Alexa Speaking Without Being Asked

Tags: alexa

Last night at midnight Alexa scared me silly. I had the volume up from playing music earlier, and she shouts out "I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that" without being prompted. Why is this? The only way to stop it is to turn it off, what is the point of having it?

Comment: Checking your [dialogue history](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201602040) might be helpful; you can [edit] to include that in the question, and you might be able to listen to the recorded audio clip to get some hints as to why it triggered.

Comment: A bit scary to hear this. I am also using Alexa but didn't experience this. One time at midnight I noticed the light glows without any prompt. I thought maybe it's updated. Your scenario is different. You can cross check this on your Alexa Mobile app - command history.

Comment: Thank guys, great answers! My daughter says it happens to her when the tv is on, mine was on too, but no one said Alexa.

Answer (score 3):

When Echo's Mics are on it is possible that some other spoken word or sound matches the wake work "Alexa". I have had a few occurrences of "Alex" and "Alexander" waking Echo.

> The only way to stop it is to turn it off

You may try turning off its Mic, when you do not wish Alexa to listen. but, functions such as Alarm will still work.